# Problem with method references when migrating from Java 8 to Java 11

Tags: java, java-11, method-reference

I'm trying to migrate some old applications that uses Java 8 libs to Java 11, but something strange happened with code that uses method references:

```
Error:(26, 46) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      unexpected static method getId(com.mongodb.BasicDBObject) found in unbound lookup)
```

The scenario looks like this:

MyOldLib.java (on Java 8 project)

```java
public class MyOldLib {
    public static String getId(BasicDBObject o) { return o.getString("id"); }
}
```

MyMigratingApplication.java (on Java 11 project)

```java
public class MyMigratingApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BasicDBObject> myList = getDataFromSomewhere();
        List<String> myIdList = myList.stream().map(MyOldLib::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

    //...
    }
}
```

Using the method reference as was done doesn't work, but if I use a lambda or encapsulate the `getId` method instead, it does work:

Using lambda:

```java
public class MyMigratingApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BasicDBObject> myList = getDataFromSomewhere();
        List<String> myIdList = myList.stream().map(data -> MyOldLib.getId(data)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    //...
    }
}
```

Encapsulating:

```java
public class MyMigratingApplication {
    static String getId(BasicDBObject data) {
        return MyOldLib.getId(data)
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BasicDBObject> myList = getDataFromSomewhere();
        List<String> myIdList = myList.stream().map(MyMigratingApplication::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    //...
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? There's any solution that minimizes the code refactor needs?

Some aditional info:

1) The MongoDB version is the same on both projects, 3.6.4.

2) This happens when I try to run the applicatin on IntelliJ IDE.

3) I'm using Maven as dependency manager.

Comment: It works fine for me on JDK-13. What version of `IntelliJ` are you using? Code under *Encapsulating* block as such wouldn't work `MyMigratingApplication::getId(data)`, you can change that to `MyMigratingApplication::getId`

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.2.3

Comment: Is IDEA using a Java 8 pre-built old project? Have you tried using File -> Invalidate caches?

Comment: does `maven clean compile` also gives the same error?

Comment: an opposite behaviere is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70499563/java-lambda-expressions-and-method-references-to-generic-methods