# Java Lambda Expressions and Method References to Generic Methods

Tags: java, generics, lambda, method-reference, functional-interface

I have a functional interface

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface SubmitterCompletable extends Submitter {
    @Override
    <T> CompletableFuture<T> submit(Callable<T> task);
}
```

and two functions

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

public final class CompletableFutureUtils {
    public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> runAsync(Callable<U> callable) {
        // ...
    }

    public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> runAsync(Callable<U> callable, Executor executor) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and I want to create `SubmitterCompletable`s from these functions using lambda expressions or method references. The first one works fine by using method references.

```java
SubmitterCompletable submitterCompletable = CompletableFutureUtils::runAsync;
```

For the second one, however, I have to use a lambda expression to pass an `Executor` and it doesn't work.

```java
Executor executor = /* ... */;
SubmitterCompletable submitterCompletable = c -> CompletableFutureUtils.runAsync(c, executor);
// Illegal lambda expression: Method submit of type SubmitterCompletable is generic
```

My question is whether there is a valid lambda expression for this case, or do I have to create an anonymous class in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue there is that "a lambda expression can be used for a functional interface only if the method in the functional interface has **NO** type parameters". (JLS11, [15.27.3 Type of a Lambda Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3)) with one exception - this is not the case for **congruent** method references.

That is why it works in your first example and doesn't in the second:

```
SubmitterCompletable submitterCompletable = CompletableFutureUtils::runAsync; (OK)
SubmitterCompletable submitterCompletable = c -> <anything> (NOT OK)
```

---

There aren't many options out there I could think of to achieve what you want:

1. Implement the interface (either in-place using an anonymous class as you've mentioned or as a standalone class).
2. Use an intermediate helper class inside your `CompletableFutureUtils` that would keep a ref to the executor and expose a method **congruent** with your Submitter's functional method which will delegate the call to the underlying `runAsync(Callable<U> callable, Executor executor)` util's method.

Example code:

```
public final static class CompletableFutureUtils {
    public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> runAsync(Callable<U> callable) {
        ...
    }

    public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> runAsync(Callable<U> callable, Executor executor) {
        ...
    }
    
    public static ExecutorRunnerProxy using(Executor executor) {
        return new ExecutorRunnerProxy(executor);
    }

    public static final class ExecutorRunnerProxy {
        private final Executor executor;

        private ExecutorRunnerProxy(Executor executor) {
            this.executor = executor;
        }

        public <T> CompletableFuture<T> runAsync(Callable<T> task) {
            return CompletableFutureUtils.runAsync(task, executor);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
SubmitterCompletable submitterCompletable = CompletableFutureUtils::runAsync; 
SubmitterCompletable submitterWithExecutor = CompletableFutureUtils.using(executor)::runAsync;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a valid lambda expression, however, you need to move the generic type in `SubmitterCompletable` from the method to the class level as long as lambda expression cannot be constructed if the generic type is defined at the method:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SubmitterCompletable<T> extends Submitter {  // notice the <T>

    @Override
    CompletableFuture<T> submit(Callable<T> task);            // reuses the generic type
}
```

```
Executor executor = /* ... */;
SubmitterCompletable<Whatever> submitterCompletable = c -> runAsync(c, executor);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will also restrict the created `SubmitterCompletable<T>` to certain `Callable<T>`s, which is not what I want. To be more clear what I mean: Imagine if the `ExecutorService` interface had a generic type `T` like this, then you could only submit tasks with specific return values `T`. With that in mind, you're not answering my question, you're changing the rules to make it work.